# Value Error: expected conv2d_21_input to have shape (224, 224, 3)

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am working with CNNS and Keras and trying to predict an image.

I have created a window sliding to predict part of the images like this:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = Image.open('data/test_dataset/06.jpg')
size = 200
step = 50

for x in range(0, img.size[0]-size, step):
    # go through y axis
    for y in range(0, img.size[1]-size, step):
        part = img.crop((x, y, x + size, y+ size))
        data = np.asarray(part.resize((244,244), resample=Image.BICUBIC))
        data = data.astype(np.float32)/255.
        model.predict(data.reshape(1, 244, 244, 3))
        #plt.imshow(part)
        #plt.show()
```

But getting the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_21_input to
>   have shape (224, 224, 3) but got array with shape (244, 244, 3)

My CNN structure looks like this: 
[CNN structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ourB.png)

I tried many things out but I have no idea how to solve this problem. Can someone help me? Many thanks in advance

Comment: It's very easy to troubleshoot this just by reading the error: your model expects images of size `(224, 224)` but you are resizing the images to `(244, 244)` (Note one is **224** and the other is **244**).

Comment: Don't understand. The model expect 244 and I resize it to 244 what the problem?

Comment: Model expects **224**, and not **244**! Let me write it: 224 = two-hundred and **twenty**-four, 244 = two-hundred and **forty**-four. Is that clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model you're trying to predict with accepts an input of shape `(224, 224, 3)`, but you're passing it an image of shape `(244, 244, 3)`.

Try this:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = Image.open('data/test_dataset/06.jpg')
size = 200
step = 50

for x in range(0, img.size[0]-size, step):
    # go through y axis
    for y in range(0, img.size[1]-size, step):
        part = img.crop((x, y, x + size, y+ size))
        data = np.asarray(part.resize((224,224), resample=Image.BICUBIC))
        data = data.astype(np.float32)/255.
        model.predict(data.reshape(1, 224, 224, 3))
```

Comment: What did you change? I can't see that :-)

Comment: The model expects (224,224,3), and not (244,244,3). I just changed that.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see it :-)